# While rebulding my project in visual studio, I am getting 2 errors on the same line error C2371

Tags: c++

> 1.error C2556: 'ulong htonf(float)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'unsigned int htonf(float)'
>   (Src\AudioRecorder.cpp)
>   2. error C2371: 'htonf' : redefinition; different basic types (Src\AudioRecorder.cpp)

```
ulong htonf(float d)
{
#ifndef __BIG_ENDIAN__
ulong a;
uchar *dst = (uchar *)&a;
uchar *src = (uchar *)&d;

dst[0] = src[3];
dst[1] = src[2];
dst[2] = src[1];
dst[3] = src[0];

return a;
#else /* really no conversion necessary, but compiler warnings =>       optimazation requried todo */
ulong a;
uchar *dst = (uchar *)&a;
uchar *src = (uchar *)&d;

dst[0] = src[0];
dst[1] = src[1];
dst[2] = src[2];
dst[3] = src[3];

return a;
#endif
}
```

This is the function htonf

Can anyone help me out for the same?

Comment: And where is the code? Post the invocation of function htonf and the overload(s) from AudioRecorder.cpp

Comment: Please inform this link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Mohit Jain, included the function htonf

Comment: Where is the function defined? Inside a class, globally? Also show us the header definition. It looks like the return type differs in the header (unsigned int instead of unsigned long).

Comment: function htonf is not defined inside the class, /*  net-conversion for double/float */  
    ulong htonf(float d);
 this is how the header definition

Comment: header file function declaration is 
    unsigned long CAF::htonf(float d);
this is the real function declaration

Answer (score 0):

Your `ulong htonf(float d)` is clashing with microsofts.
Each overloaded function must have a distinct different parameter list.

```
unsigned __int32 __inline htonf( float value)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj710198(v=vs.85).aspx

```
class C {
   int func();
   double func();   // <----- error C2556
   int func(int i);   // ok parameter lists differ
};
```